# Add protocol to gammu

Tags: kannel, gammu

By default gammu have support for most standard modem. I have a very particular modem with some special requirements and I would like to add a protocol to gammu.
Is there a guide for this somewhere or someone who can list the basic steps for me?

EDIT: @user1664784 recommended to look att Kannel, and actually any system able to handle incoming and outgoing SMS is acceptable as long as it is stable. But I need to know how to modify the system so that I can handle a specific protocol. It is AT-based but a slight dialect. So any suggestion of a system handling SMS from a device connected over serial port is interesting. I need to find a system where someone can give me information on where in the source code I can begin adding a new AT-based protocol.

If someone have done some sample code in this area it would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can help you with Kannel , but not Gammu.

Comment: @user1664784 interesting, so you are saying I can connect Kannel to a serial port modem as well ? Thought it was just direct connection to SMSC

Comment: yes, Kannel connects to Modem on serial ports or USB mounted to com port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends how much different it is from standard AT commands.

- If the difference is minor (eg. needs custom initialization), it can be easily achieved by feature flags. This can be seein [ATGEN_PostConnect which handles initialization for ZTE or Huawei devices](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/blob/master/libgammu/phone/at/atgen.c#L2089).
- If the differences are big, you will probably need to write own driver, which will fall back to AT in some cases. Something similar can be seen in the [AT OBEX driver which switches Bluetooth connection between OBEX and IrMC modes](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/blob/master/libgammu/phone/atobex/atobex.c).

I think we used to have documentation on adding support for new devices, but I'm unable to find it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There are some command that will have some extra parameters. But almost like normal AT-commands. Would you count this as minor difference?

Comment: Looks like it would fit.